# How can I do logging in Azure Web Jobs?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

So I have tried:

```
Trace.TraceInformation("Trace.Information Found message on queue");
Debug.WriteLine("Debug Found message on queue"); 
Trace.WriteLine("Trace.WriteLine Found message on queue");
Console.WriteLine("Console.WriteLine Found message on queue");
```

But neither of them outputs to the Azure portal Web Jobs output log.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Later edit: 
Since the Beta version, the answer below is no longer correct. In order to log messages, you have to use a TextWriter now as shown in these samples: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/Program.cs

---

Console.WriteLine should work. If that doesn't work, can you please post more code?

For messages written from inside a function, the logs should show up on the function invocation page.

For messages written outside of a function, the logs should show up in the job output log.

Comment: Console.WriteLine doesn't work for me either. Tested in Main() and in Function(). That said the "the function invocation page" currently seams to be broken - yesterday I did see the  function call statistics and list - today its just a message "Do more with Windows Azure WebJobs SDK. ...". Everything else is working jobs are being triggerd.

Comment: With the Beta release, we've changed the way logging works. You have to use a TextWriter now as shown in these samples: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/AzureWebJobs/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/Program.cs

Comment: Is there actual documentation for this?

Comment: What part of https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/Program.cs actually logs anything?

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci the link http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/AzureWebJobs/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/Program.cs is broken. It goes to a repository but it doesn't have that file.

Comment: The entire source code was moved to GitHub https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples

Answer (score 3):

Console.WriteLine worked for me but log.WriteLine (as per the SDK samples) did not.

Turned out I needed to set the Webjob connection strings in the portal even though I had AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage defined in the App.config.

Comment: log.WriteLine is not working for me either (and I **have** those connection strings in the portal!). Console.WriteLine works though. I wish there was some good documentation on the whole TextWriter approach from a new user's perspective.