# How to use logging in Azure Web Jobs?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-webjobs

Please advice on the best practice to use in Azure Web Job logging? Still haven't found a proper mechanism to use for this?

Logging levels - Info, Error mainly are needed.

I have referred the below links.

[Logging in Azure web jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125755/logging-in-azure-web-jobs)

[How can I do logging in Azure Web Jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961594/how-can-i-do-logging-in-azure-web-jobs)

[Logging in Azure web jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125755/logging-in-azure-web-jobs)

Comment: What do you want use log to do? Trace message or print information or error?

Comment: @JoeyCai - to log info and error both.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following mechanism to overcome this problem.

Enable diagnostic logging - [Refer this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log)

For output stream logging use -> Console.Out.Writeline();

For Error stream logging use -> Console.Error.Writeline()

This will create the relevant CSV file under the selected blob container without truncating the logs.